# Error while run Sphinx search service

Tags: ubuntu, docker, sphinx

I need install sphinxsearch for Mailpiler.
When i try to run it i got got that:

```
root@78c3f1ee01ed:/var/log# /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start
Starting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
precaching index 'main1'
precaching index 'main2'                                    
precaching index 'main3'                                    
precaching index 'main4'                                    
precaching index 'dailydelta1'                              
precaching index 'delta1'                                   
precaching index 'tag1'                                     
precaching index 'note1'                                    
precached 8 indexes in 0.003 sec                            
 ERROR.
```

Log is empty.

```
root@78c3f1ee01ed:/var/log# ls -al sphinxsearch/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 sphinxsearch root   4096 Oct 21  2013 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 root         syslog 4096 Dec  1 11:07 ..
```

witch `tail -f /var/log/searchd.log &`:

```
root@78c3f1ee01ed:/var/log# /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start
Starting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
precaching index 'main1'
precaching index 'main2'                                    
precaching index 'main3'                                    
precaching index 'main4'                                    
precaching index 'dailydelta1'                              
precaching index 'delta1'                                   
precaching index 'tag1'                                     
precaching index 'note1'                                    
precached 8 indexes in 0.003 sec                            
 ERROR.
root@78c3f1ee01ed:/var/log# [Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.219 2014] [  920] Child process 921 has been forked
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.219 2014] [  921] listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.219 2014] [  921] listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.223 2014] [  921] binlog: replaying log /var/data/binlog/binlog.001
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.223 2014] [  921] binlog: replay stats: 0 rows in 0 commits; 0 updates; 0 indexes
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.223 2014] [  921] binlog: finished replaying /var/data/binlog/binlog.001; 0.0 MB in 0.000 sec
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.223 2014] [  921] binlog: finished replaying total 1 in 0.000 sec
[Mon Dec  1 14:47:38.223 2014] [  921] accepting connections
```

Looks like it's running, but still output error.

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch at start bash run function running

```
 start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        do_start
        [ -n "$STARTDELAY" ] && sleep $STARTDELAY

        if running ; then
            echo "$NAME."
        else
            echo " ERROR."
        fi
        ;;
```

running looking for PIDFILE.

```
running()
{
# Check if the process is running looking at /proc
# (works for all users)

    # No pidfile, probably no daemon present
    [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] && return 1
    # Obtain the pid and check it against the binary name
    pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
    running_pid $pid $DAEMON || return 1
    return 0
}
```

Default PIDFILE is set in /var/run/sphinhsearch

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
```

But in my config file "`using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...`" PID has been saved to "`pid_file                = /var/run/piler/searchd.pid`"

After changing PID location "`PIDFILE=/var/run/piler/searchd.pid`" all works correctly.

```
Starting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
precaching index 'main1'
precaching index 'main2'                                    
precaching index 'main3'                                    
precaching index 'main4'                                    
precaching index 'dailydelta1'                              
precaching index 'delta1'                                   
precaching index 'tag1'                                     
precaching index 'note1'                                    
precached 8 indexes in 0.003 sec                            
sphinxsearch.
```

Answer (score 0):

That 'ERROR' doesnt appear to come from sphinx. Can't find any case where sphinx will output just a bland error, it at least tries to explain. Check the source of the init script maybe it will have a clue.

Although having said that, I know from experience, sphinx doesnt like when the 'binlog_path' is not setup right. It tends to just unceremoniously die, without any message (but the log still shows the server starting up, before it die).

Check the folder 1) defined in sphinx.conf 2) exists as a folder and 3) writable by the sphinxsearch user.

Comment: I set binlog_path. Error are still the same. I set 777 to all where sphinx try to write.

Comment: That was only a possible suggestion. Did you check to see if can figure if the init script will output that ERROR (and if so under what conditions) ??

Comment: `if running ; then
            echo "$NAME."
        else
            echo " ERROR."
        fi`